# Integration Test suite failures after move to SpringBoot 2 Mockito 3.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

Our project is moving to SpringBoot 2 (using spring-starter-test) and Mockito 3.x .
In the integration tests, I converted the beans from `@Mock` to `@MockBean` annotation , removed `@InjectMocks` where it was not needed and also the MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) [either way not sure if it makes a difference]
When I run the test class individually (containing multiple test methods] , it runs successfully.
On running the whole test suite (3k tests), I start getting the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:95)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1601.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1600.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect..invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [etc.VerificationDao$MockitoMock$1412655972]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [etc /service/etc/etc/VerificationDao$MockitoMock$1412655972.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApp)

//Base Test is extending Spring4Runner.class and using context.xml
public class NewServiceTest extends BaseTest {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier('newServiceV1')
NewServiceV1 newService!;


@MockBean
StartServiceImpl startServiceMock

@Autowired
ScoresService scoresService

@Autowired
StartService startService

@Autowired
ProductV2 productV2

@MockBean
VerificationDao verificationDaoMock;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    setMock(startServiceMock)// will have some mock doAnswer etc
}
```

Is it for some reason that the mocks are getting accessed ,before being created or something else altogether? Any help would be appreciated . Have been at it for a day or so now.

Update: Somehow the mocks are coming as one of the configuration classes that Spring is trying to load. For some reason, they are not getting cleared/reset . It does not happen in all combination of test cases.

Comment: The stacktrace contains the strange path "/service/etc/etc/VerificationDao", is there anything unusual about the VerificationDao class?

Comment: That was a sample path I had inserted in the trace. Though I am still not very clear on what might be happening, but it looks like when I am giving @MockBean on the implementation class and not the interface, Spring is trying to configure 2 beans one of type Mockito and the other the regular bean (which was defined as a component)

Comment: Best would bei to create a minimal Test Project in GitHub which people could try and get working.

Comment: Yes, that would have the been the simpler way to go but since we have so many test cases that need migration, it might work with one test case but not the suite , which is what is happening currently. I was able to understand to some extent why the above issue comes. When Spring finds any other test class (not necessarily the one which is throwing the error) and that class has the field Mocked to an implementation and not an interface , it tries  to find the MockitoVersion of the implementation (since it is a Spring component).

Comment: I was able to get past it by @Mock to the interface , with a qualifier instead of the implementation class. Though I feel MockBean is very sensitive and can give issues,

Comment: `@Mock` and `@MockBean` serve completely different purposes. You can't replace them with each other and expect your tests to work. The first is used for unit tests that don't invlove any Spring Test Context at all. You use it to replace any collaborator when unit testing your services. `@MockBean` however is used to replace a bean inside a Spring Context with a mocked version of it. This usually happens if you write a test for your controller (`@WebMvcTest`) and mock any service class that this controlelr uses.

Comment: I see.  We are using @Mock with Integration tests (not controller). The beans were being replaced by Mockito versions in the applicationContext prior to the move to SpringBoot. So the thought was that it can be replaced by MockBean.